# Batch insertion in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I am new to neo4j. I have created graph database in neo4j i.e "my.graphdb" which also include schema indexes. Now I want to use this database into my java program. For that I used batch insertion. Also I am creating schema indexes in my java program. But when I run the program it gives me following exception.

Exception :

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema modification is currently not available
```

through the BatchDatabase  API.

In short, I want to use my existing graph database (my.graphdb) into new java program. Moreover, I want to use my existing data and indexes present in my.graphdb to insert new nodes and relationships.

Please let me know what should I do ?

Comment: Your question is confusing, can you detail the steps you took and show code / setup? And also share the full stack trace and the place where it occurred.

Answer (score 0):

The `BatchGraphDatabase` should not be used.

Use the `BatchInserter` or the transactional `EmbeddedGraphDatabase`.

The Batchinserter also supports the creation of schema indexes which are populated at shutdown (test with a small dataset first, it can take a while, will be faster in 2.0.1).

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. I have managed set up my database.